# How to run tests from outer class and nested inner classes simultaneously in JUnit 4?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have such an example of test class with inner static test class inside. I need to run all tests simultaneously in one run. I use JUnit 4.13.

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class OuterClassTest {

  public static class InnerClassTest {

    @Test
    public void innerTest() {
    }

  }

  @Test
  public void outerTest() {
  }

}
```

If I run `OuterClassTest` like this, it only runs `innerTest`.

If I remove `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)` annotation from `OuterClassTest`, it only runs `outerTest`.

**How can I run this class, so that both tests run simultaneously?**